# Disable Export/Print option in SSRS for some reports only

Tags: reporting-services

I found out some cool code-related solutions to make the Export/Print option disabled in SSRS, like these:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2b849acd-e9cb-4e66-b894-ca9531839db3/reportviewer-2010how-to-hide-pdf-in-export-option-in-reportviewer?forum=sqlreportingservices.

These seem working but unfortunately for all reports that have been created so far. What if I would need it for specified reports only? How should I change the code option for that, provided that it is possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: it is better to place the code in the question, than adding a link

Comment: You could also just disalble/enable  it in properties->hidden and then use an expression to do that